# C++ free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++

I've looked at similar questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729395/error-free-invalid-next-size-fast), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436181/c-error-free-invalid-next-size-fast-different-behaviour-of-c-program-on), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206714/c-error-free-invalid-next-size-fast)), but I still can't figure this out. On a few test cases, I'm getting the error and can't make sense of it. The error I'm getting is:

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

My code uses the Robot Coin Collection algorithm. My implementation of it is below:

```
int collectTens( vector< vector<int> > grid ) {

vector<vector<int>> result(grid.size(), vector<int>(grid.size(), 0));
int rows = grid.size();
int cols = grid[0].size();

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j] % 10 != 0) {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

result[0][0] = grid[0][0];

for (int k = 1; k < cols; k++) {
    result[0][k] = result[0][k - 1] + grid[0][k];
}

for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
    result[i][0] = result[i - 1][0] + grid[i][0];
    for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
        result[i][j] = max(result[i - 1][j], result[i][j - 1]) + grid[i][j];
    }
}

cerr << result[rows - 1][cols - 1] << endl;

return result[rows - 1][cols - 1];
}
```

In the test cases that the error occurs, the result can be outputted using stderr but will not be able to return anything due to the error. Which is the part that doesn't really make sense to me, because it is the same position in the 2D vector.

Comment: Use a memory debugger like valgrind or whatever people use on your platform. (If you want us to help, you have to give us enough code to reproduce the error. Perhaps the vectors in the vector passed to `collectTens` aren't all the same size. That would blow things up.)

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried to use valgrind but had problems running it. Figuring out how to use tools like these will definitely help in the future though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
vector<vector<int>> result(grid.size(), vector<int>(grid.size(), 0));
```

creates square grid, not a rectangular grid. You probably meant to use:

```
vector<vector<int>> result(grid.size(), vector<int>(grid[0].size(), 0));
                                                        ^^^^
```

I suggest using:

```
int rows = grid.size();
int cols = grid[0].size();
vector<vector<int>> result(rows, vector<int>(cols, 0));
```

Comment: You're right, that's what I overlooked. I kept thinking the error was in my algorithm instead. Thanks!